# Need help with CSS Tabs & Border Color

Tags: css

I am trying to replicate the effect I see

[image]

Currently I have http://jsfiddle.net/GWkk3/

[image]

How can I remove the border between the active li and the 2nd level nav?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw the border on the parent `<li>` elements rather than the child `<ul>`. Add/change these properties:

```
.appTabs li {
    border-width: 1px 0 1px 1px; /* was 1px 0 0 1px */
}

.appTabs li.active {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
}

.appTabs li ul {
    top: 25px; /* was 24px */
}
```

And **remove** this property:

```
.appTabs li ul {
    border-top: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

That gets us [this far](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/YLbq3/1/):

[image]

Now the inner border just needs to be extended all the way to the right (I'm working on that part).

Answer (score 0):

Make the active tab have 1px extra bottom padding, and have a bottom margin of -1px, so it sits over the line.

Comment: You're right. The whole thing is styled a lot differently than I would have done it... so my quick fix won't work. Sorry.